# C# int & int32 declaration

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# so forgive me, but I'm just wanting to know why do I have to convert int to int32?

For example I declare `lowerRange` as an int, but then later on when I am to read user input, I have to convert it to int32 otherwise it gives me an error saying I "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'.

OR I'm assuming that I have to convert because the user is entering a string and I have to convert it to an int, which in that case makes me wonder why I have to declare `lowerRange` as an int the first place?

```
int lowerRange;
...
lowerRange = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: `int` has number characteristics. you can do numeric operations on `int` while that is not possible on `string`, yes user input is string.

Comment: "why do I have to convert int to int32" - it is not really possible to answer this question because they are different names for the same type and you can't express conversion between them in C#... Converting string to int on other hand is covered in on or two hundreds of questions...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns a `string` that needs to be parsed and converted to an integer (using `Convert.ToInt32`) if you want to assign it to the `lowerRange` integer variable.

So basically you have this:

```
int lowerRange;
...
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
lowerRange = Convert.ToInt32(userInput);
```

Also notice that the reason why the `ReadLine` method returns a string is because the user can enter anything as input. So you might want to validate that the user has entered a valid number using the `TryParse` method, otherwise the `ToInt32` method will throw an exception:

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
if (int.TryParse(userInput, out lowerRange))
{
    // The user entered a valid integer you can use the lowerRange variable here
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
}
```

Comment: I would be a bit conservative using `TryParse` because it will return a `0` if non-valid string was entered which might lead to unexpected behavior if `0` meant something in the upcoming stages. Using `try`/`catch` gives you more control on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to convert it to int32 otherwise it
>   gives me an error saying I "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'int'.

Because Console.Readline() return string which is from user input.

> OR I'm assuming that I have to convert because the user is entering a
>   string and I have to convert it to an int, which in that case makes me
>   wonder why I have to declare lowerRange as an int the first place?

You don't need to declare `lowerRange` as an integer IF you want to use it as a string.  But if you want to use it as a integer then you need to convert it (using `Convert` class).